# Add new column model_has_permission table

Tags: laravel, authentication, permissions, categories, roles

I am using the Spatie laravel-permission package, and I need to modify the model_has_permission table to add a new column, "category_id," where I can store the category for each permission. Now when I want to add a new permission to a user (model), it works fine, but of course, the new column category_id leaves empty. I saw that the model_has_permissions is updated by a sync() function using the permissions(): MorphToMany function.

How can I update the permissions() function to update the category_id column? Now it only updates the default columns.

Comment: Are you using the Spatie permission package  ?

Comment: yes i m using spatie

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

1. Using the `Permission` relation as a classic `morphToMany` Relationship
2. Extending the Spatie Permission model

In option 1 you can use the `Permission` relationship as a normal `morphToMany` relation so all the methods are available [(doc)](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-model-structure) :

```
(new User())->permissions()->attach($permissionIds, ['category_id'=>1]);
(new User())->permissions()->sync($permissionIds, ['category_id'=>1]);
```

Option 2, extending the Permission model by adding only properties/methods that you need as stated in the Spatie [doc](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/advanced-usage/extending#extending)

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission; 

class customPermission extends Permission
{
        // You might set a public property like guard_name or connection, or override other Eloquent Model methods/properties
}
```

Comment: Please mark as answered /upvote. Thank you